# How to access outer element inside Repeater?

Tags: javascript, xml, observable, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder

**Javascript**

```
var pageData = new Observable({
    appointmentsList: appointmentsList,
    user_role: ''
});

exports.onLoaded = function (args) {
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
    pageData.set('user_role', appSettings.getString('role'));
```

**XML**

```
<Repeater items="{{appointmentsList.booking_dates.bookings}}">
    <Repeater.itemsLayout>
        <StackLayout class="appointment-rows" />
    </Repeater.itemsLayout>
    <Repeater.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout>
            <WrapLayout visibility="{{ user_role === 'agency' ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }}">
                <Label text="{{user_name}}" class="row-client-name row-client-name-new" />
            </WrapLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Repeater.itemTemplate>
 </Repeater>
```

In above snippet that problem is i am not able to access `user_role` inside `Repeater`. 
Can anybody help me how to access outer element inside `Repeater` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#example-4-creating-listview-child-items-based-on-the-itemtemplate, You can try something like this:

```
<WrapLayout visibility="{{$parents['Repeater'].user_role,$parents['Repeater'].user_role === 'agency' ? 'visibile' : 'collapse' }}">
```

or this way

```
<WrapLayout visibility="{{$parents['Page'].user_role,$parents['Page'].user_role === 'agency' ? 'visibile' : 'collapse' }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `$parent` or `$parents[]` property.

I believe:

`<WrapLayout visibility="{{ $parent.user_role, $parent.user_role === 'agency' ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }}">`

Should work.    However since this is in a repeater, I don't believe it does anything weird to the parent binding; but if that doesn't work -- you can simply do this:

`<WrapLayout visibility="{{ $parents['Page'].user_role, $parents['Page'].user_role === 'agency' ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }}">`

NativeScript Documentation on this feature: http://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#binding-to-a-parent-binding-context

Comment: I have `RadListView` in parent of `Repeater `. Does that matter ?

Comment: Yes, then you will need to use $parents['Page'] to access it.  $parent would only go up one level, to whatever is bound to the RadListView.

Comment: Guess this works fine at getting `user_role` but it is not able to evaluate condition for `$parents['Page'].user_role === 'agency' ? 'visible' : 'collapse'`

Comment: Did you wrote full way ? `{{ $parents['Page'].user_role, $parents['Page'].user_role === 'agency' ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }}` and not `only {{$parents['Page'].user_role === 'agency' ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }}`

Comment: `visibility="{{ $parents['Page'].user_role, $parents['Page'].user_role == 'agency' ? 'visibile' : 'collapse' }}"`

Comment: **SO SORRY** there was typo in `visibile`. Thanks

Comment: @MarekMaszay, what does that comma (`,`) syntax mean before and after having data

Comment: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#using-expressions-for-bindings @SaiUnique check this for answer

Comment: This doesn't seem to work now checkout https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=FaTrgV&v=20.